# Win32: Changing Program Icon

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources

I had originally decided that IDI_ICON1 would be a good fit for my program:

```
wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (HINST_THISCOMPONENT, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
```

The icon then appeared in the top left of the title menu for my main window and for the .exe file in Windows explorer.

I decided I liked IDI_ICON2 better, so I changed:

```
wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (HINST_THISCOMPONENT, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON2));
```

Now icon2 appears in the top left of the title menu, but the icon in Windows explorer is still shown as icon1. What am I missing?

Comment: This might be due to caching. Try moving into a different folder or renaming it. Otherwise try rebooting.

Comment: I just rebooted and rebuilt the application but it's still showing icon1. I also copied the program into a different folder and still icon1. Is this field of the window class the only area in Win32 which deals with the program icon?

Comment: Then I guess I guessed wrong... XD

Comment: It can be IconCache.db ... close explorer.exe, delete the file, then reboot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Explorer takes the first icon in your executable. That will be the one with the lowest id. Try managing your resources so that IDI_ICON2 is defined to be a lower integer than IDI_ICON1.

Comment: It seems that you are correct. I swapped the IDs for the icons and icon1 seems to be that which is shown in explorer regardless of the icon set in the window class. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @user974967: Just want to clarify that window classes have nothing to do with executables and their resources.

Comment: The .rc file gets compiled with a resource compiler and then linked in with the executable. Is this correct? The only area in the code that deals with icons (that I know of) is the window class settings. But, I guess that just determines the icon shown in the title bar.

Comment: Also, do you know anything about how to determine the icon shown when you delete, copy/replace, or in the "preview"? I'd rather not muck with the .rc file if there is a way to do this in VS.